# How to convert predicted log odds to predict chance something wouldn't happen - other level?

Tags: logistic-regression

I want to find the predicted log odds of someone not dropping out of high school when I have the predicted log odds that they will drop out of high school. For probability I know it would be 1 - the prediction, but what would it be for log odds? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let `Y` be the event they drop out of high school. You have this: `log ( odds(Y=1) )` and you want `log ( odds(Y=0) )`. First, we quickly define what odds are:

`odds(x) = p(x) / ( 1 - p(x) )`

Therefore:

`odds (Y=0) = ( P(Y=0) / P(Y=1) ) = 1 / odds (Y=1)`

Now you can easily take the log:

`log(1 / odds (Y=1) = - log ( odds (Y=1) )`

And you're done.